# eps2eps, epstopdf, ghostscript Error: /undefined in --definefont-- (Usage from Matlab)

Tags: bash, matlab, pdf, ghostscript, postscript

i'm currently writing a script in Matlab using eps2eps and epstopdf. When i use eps2eps or epstopdf from Matlab, the following happens:

```
>> system('eps2eps TEMP97062.ps TEMP97062.eps');
Error: /undefined in --definefont--
Operand stack:
   false   CMR10   --dict:12/21(L)--   Font   definefont   --dict:30/32(L)--   unknownerror
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1    %stopped_push   1900   1   3   %oparray_pop   1899   1   3   %oparray_pop   1883   1   3   %oparray_pop   1771   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   1762   3   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   1850   3   4   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1171/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:81/200(L)--   --dict:1171/1684(ro)(G)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

**BUT:
If i use eps2eps from bash, everything works flawless.**

May this be an issue with fonts not being found?

What i have done so far:
I checked the environmental values of both bash and matlab, and the ones pointing to fonts are the same.
I added the /usr/share/fonts/Type1/ directory to the matlab path. No changes.
Google i found some other problems where something was undefined. Nothing seemed to be related or the suggested changes didn't apply or work.
I tried to reproduce the problem with another system, there it works.

My System:

```
Arch Linux 64-Bit with KDE (Kernel 3.13.6-1-ARCH)
Ghostscript 9.10
epstopdf 2.21
Matlab 2013a for Unix
```

Any suggestions what is causing this and how i can resolve this issue?

Thanks for your help!

//Edit: [I uploaded one of the files i'm using](http://webuser.hs-furtwangen.de/~muchamat/temp/TEMP97062.ps)

///Edit: I tried to change GS_PATH from "/home/matze/.fonts" to "/home/matze/.fonts:/usr/share/fonts/TTF:/usr/share/fonts/Type1:/usr/share/fonts" from within Matlab. But if i print the variable again, it still has the old content.

Comment: The error is quite clear: the font "CMR10" cannot be located. You set a path but did you *add* the font to GS? "To add fonts of your own, you must edit Fontmap to include at the end an entry for your new font", first hit on "ghostscript add font".

Comment: Thanks, ill try that after sleeping. But if the font is not installed correctly, why does then eps2eps work directly from shell?

Answer (score 1):

The MATLAB `system` command sets environment variables differently from a regular shell that you would open from a login shell or with xterm, etc. Try explicitly specifying the path to the fonts:

```
system('eps2eps -I/usr/share/fonts/Type1/ TEMP97062.ps TEMP97062.eps');
```

or

```
system('eps2eps -sFONTPATH=/usr/share/fonts/Type1/ TEMP97062.ps TEMP97062.eps');
```

Try any other folders that might contain CMR10, separating multiple paths with `:`.

---

Another possible solution is to fix whatever environment variable is broken. In bash, check the environment variables `GS_LIB`, `GS_LIB_DEFAULT`, `GS_FONTPATH` and `PATH` (see [Section 8.10 Font Look Up](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#Font_lookup) of How to use Ghostscript) for anything font-related. Then [update the path used by processes spawned by MATLAB with `setenv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setenv.html).  For example,

```
setenv('GS_LIB', [getenv('GS_LIB') ':/usr/share/fonts/Type1/']);
setenv('PATH', [getenv('PATH') ':/usr/share/fonts/Type1/']);
% ... any other relevant variables
system('eps2eps TEMP97062.ps TEMP97062.eps');
```

Comment: I tried adding all folders that contain fonts to either PATH, GS_LIB and to sFONTPATH. Still the same error.

Comment: See my second edit, adding to GS_LIB didn't quite work.

Comment: @Martze If you do a `getenv` after the `setenv(...,[getenv(...) ':/new'])`, then what you tried to add is not in that variable?  Sounds like a problem with `setenv`.